# Simple Insertion Sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I had written a simple insertion sort program but the output is not coming correctly.

```
class InsertionSort{
    public static void main(String h[]){
    int[] a = {5,4,3,2,1};
    int i,j,temp;
        for(i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            j = i-1; 
            while(i>0 && a[j] > a[i]){
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        for(int x=0; x<a.length;x++){
            System.out.println(a[x]);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://webthanga.blogspot.in/2016/02/generic-type-insertion-sort-this-below.html) for a Generic type insertion sorting

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
/*this program sort in ascending order by insertion sort */  
class InsertionSort{
public static void main(String h[]){
int[] a = {100,12,31, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] > a[i] )
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i=j;
            j--;

        }
    }
for(int x=0; x<a.length;x++){
    System.out.println(a[x]);   
  }
}
}
/*this program sort in descending order by insertion sort */  
class InsertionSort{
public static void main(String h[]){
int[] a = {100,12,31, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j] < a[i] )
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i=j;
            j--;

        }
    }
for(int x=0; x<a.length;x++){
    System.out.println(a[x]);   
  }
}
}
```

Comment: @HarshKanakhara In the outer loop the array is sorted below i and we make i larger. In the inner loop we move the element starting at i down by swapping neigbours. But this answer swaps neighbours by making i smaller, even though the array was about to be sorted up to i. So it works but it does extra work because you have to loop through the outer loop to get i back up to where it just was. Notice that in this inner loop j is always i-1 so you swap element i with i-1. You should just start j at i and swap j with j-1 and leave i alone. See my updated answer.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara This program never terminates when the array has two elements with the same value. First, the = in the >= uselessly moves equal elements and i and j down into the sorted values. Then, when i is made larger the old equal element will do the same. Etc.

Comment: hi @philipxy thanks for your observation. looping problem of previous code not exist in updated code. can you please check and give your up vote please.

Comment: @ mohammadtanvirulislam & @HarshKanakhara The infinite loop has been fixed since my last comment. But the comment before that still applies. This answer is not an insertion sort. (Basically, it is lucky to be a sort at all.) You can fix it as I described. Then it will be the same as in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

At the top of the outer loop the array is sorted below element `i`. You don't want to move `i` back down into the array. In the inner loop `j` moves the new element that starts at `i` down into the sorted array by repeatedly switching with the next one down.

```
for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
    for (j = i; j > 0 && a[j-1] > a[j]; j--){
        temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j-1];
        a[j-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {100, 12, 31, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int[] doInsertionSort(int[] input) {
    int reverse;
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {

            System.out.println("compare " + input[j - 1] + " to " + input[j]);

            if (input[j] < input[j - 1]) {
                reverse = input[j];
                System.out.println("Reverse: "+ reverse);

                input[j] = input[j - 1];
                input[j - 1] = reverse;

                new printNumbers(input);
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}

 printNumbers(int[] input) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Insertion Sort**

```
public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arry1 = {55,12,43,27,54,34,77,3,15,19};
        int[] arry2 = insertionSort(arry1);
        System.out.println("Insertion Sort Demo:");
        for(int i:arry2){
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] arr){

        int temp;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i ; j > 0 ; j--){
                if(arr[j] < arr[j-1]){
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
```

**Program Output:**

Insertion Sort Demo:

3 12 15 19 27 34 43 54 55 77

Answer (score -1):

## [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

---

Worst-case Time Complexity is O(n²)

```js
// Insertion Sort In-Place

function insertionSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j > 0; j--) {
      if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
        [arr[j], arr[j - 1]] = [arr[j - 1], arr[j]];
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

const arr = [5,1,9,2,0,6,4,3,8,7];

console.log(insertionSort(arr)); // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Insertion sort is a another sorting algorithm for sorting array elements.This algorithm is better than selection sort algorithm or bubble sort algorithm.Worst case time complexity and average case time complexity is (n^2).Best case time complexity is (n) .Worst case space complexity is (n) and best case space complexity is constant(1).Let's see how to implement insertion sort algorithm.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class insertion_sort{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Size of array :");
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    int[] num=new int[n];
    int i,j,tmp,tmp2;


    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        num[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        tmp=num[i];
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(num[i-j-1]>tmp){
                tmp2=num[i-j-1];
                num[i-j-1]=tmp;
                num[i-j]=tmp2;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.print(num[i]+"  ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

We can use a cursor.

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] elements) {
    for(int i=1;i<elements.length;i++) {            
        int cursor = i;
        for(int j=i;j>=0;j--) {
            if(elements[j]>elements[cursor]) {
                int temp = elements[j];
                elements[j] = elements[cursor];
                elements[cursor] = temp;                    
                cursor = j;                 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Sorting {
    
    
    public static void insertionSort(int[] data){
        
        for(int i=1;i<data.length;i++){
            
            int insert = data[i];
            int index = i;
            
            while(0<index && insert < data[index-1]){
                data[index]=data[index-1];
                index--;
            }
            data[index]=insert;
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();
        int[] data = generator.ints(30, 10, 20).toArray();
        

        insertionSort(data);
        System.out.println("Sorted array: "+Arrays.toString(data));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on what the code is doing.  Code dumping is not an accepted practice here.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void insertionsort(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

                    int[] input = { 4, 2, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1 };
                    arr(input);
        }
        private static void printNumbers(int[] input) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        }

        public static void arr (int array[]){    
                int n = array.length;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            int key = array[j];
            int i = j-1;
            while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) {
                array [i+1] = array [i];
                i--;
            }
            array[i+1] = key;
            printNumbers(array);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your post?

Comment: This is done in a another method. Not in the main method

Answer (score -2):

This is tested and works

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] array) {
    int temp, j;

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        temp = array[i];

        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (array[j] > temp) {
                array[j+1] = array[j];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        array[j + 1] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the nos");
        num = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the "+num+" integers");
        int array []= new int[num];
        for(int count = 0;count<num; count++ )
        {
            array[count] = s.nextInt(); 
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            key = array[i];
            j = i-1;
            while(j>=0 && array[j]>key)
            {
                array [j+1] = array[j];
                j=j-1;
            }

            array[j+1] = key;
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted array");

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)

        {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

While loop is unnecessary here,

```
                if ((a[j] < a[i]))
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
```

Comment: A loop is needed to keep moving the jth element down while it is too big. So the code in the question is missing a j--. So it can be replaced by an if but it is wrong. But the code has other problems too. Also your < should be >.